# Get info from textbox without submit button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, textbox

How can I do this? I basically want to call a function where I get the info from the textbox once the user is done entering info. I.e., after they click off of the text box. I couldn't find the clear way to do this. Is there an API for event/actions and what you can do on each input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `blur` event:

```
yourTextBox.onblur = function() {
    console.log(yourTextBox.value);
};
```

or

```
yourTextBox.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    console.log(yourTextBox.value);
});
```

See the [documentation for the `blur` event on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur).